# Hiding .php extensions with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a small site that contains two pages, the homepage (index.php) and a booking (booking.php) page which I would like to hide their extensions.

I am using the following code in my .htaccess file but it doesn't seem to work as I'd like.

What I am trying to do is simply make booking.php appear as example.com/booking and my index.php always use example.com.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-\s]+)/?$ /$1.php [NC,L]
Redirect /booking.php /booking
Redirect /index.php /
```

Answer (score 0):

I would redirect all non-asset related requests to index.php using something like the following for your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [qsa]
```

Then inside your index.php file, do something like:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/")
{
    //index page code
} elseif ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/booking")
{
    //booking page code
} else
{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
```

This way it's relatively easy to add additional pages without touching your .htaccess and you can keep any included files etc out of your webroot.

The lines "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d" and "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f" check to see if a requested file exists e.g. an image
before sending the request to index.php which is effectively a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `mod-alias` (Redirect directive) with `mod-rewrite` (RewriteRule directive) . These are two different apache modules with different runtime behaviour. You can use the following mod-rewrite rules :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# redirect /index.php and /booking.php to their extension - less versions
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(index|booking)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ /%1 [L,R]
#rewrite /index and /booking  to original destination 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-\s]+)/?$ /$1.php [NC,L]
```